# innodb and mysql index diffence after 5.1.47 to 5.5.8 upgrade

Tags: mysql

i have a running 5.1.47 versioned slave, which i upgraded to 5.5.8 almost without anyproblem.

Except one. The thing is, there is that index cause i can not create same job index with same name but with different name. But somehow mysql doesnot get it. 
I am stuck. and keep getting this message on mysqld.log. 
For now i added another index with different name doing same job and user of slave is going good for now. But i need to fix this so i can upgrade other slave too.

Error table x/users contaions 10 indexes inside Innodb, which is different from the number of indexes 9 defined in mysql.

Anyone face such similar problem?

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried issuing a `REPAIR` ?

Answer (score 0):

According to Google Translate of [this blog entry](http://tolgaercan.blogspot.com/2010/12/migrate-mysql-51x-to-558.html) (which n.b. isn't great so I might've misread it) you might want do dump the whole database and import it back. This way the database will rebuild all indexes and it might just do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

i solved that way. But when i export from 5.5.8 and index was not in mysqldump file, so i add manually and it worked. But there was data inconsistency 6 records was mismatch.
The odd thing is, it doesnot use index, it doesnot let you recreate one with the same name, and its not on show create table list, but its there, same index can be created via different name but not that one and that one is not listed at all.
Somehow after import 6 records was different then other tables after start slave again.
So for inconsistency i start from all over and it worked.
I did, copy data portion of a slave to 5.5.8 side and then start and mysql_upgrade it again.
And this time i had no problem at all. I dont know how come it works but it worked.